# Preciso separar strings para poder importar para o mysql

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso separar cada string para poder importar para o banco de dados, como eu faria?

link do arquivo qual estou testando https://camisetasdecorrida.com.br/usuarios2.csv

```
            <?php 

            include_once("../conn/conexao.php");

            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {

                $filename = $_FILES["file1"];

                if ($filename["error"]) {
                    throw new Exception("Error: ".$filename["error"]);
                }

                $dirUploads = "../uploads";

                if (move_uploaded_file($filename["tmp_name"], $dirUploads . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename["name"])) {
                    echo "Upload Realizado com sucesso";
                }else {

                    throw new Exception("Não foi possivel fazer o upload.");


                }
            }

            $filename = $dirUploads . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
            $filename["name"];


            if(file_exists($filename)) {

                $file = fopen($filename, "r");

                $headers = explode(",", fgets($file));

                $data = array();

                while ($row = utf8_encode(fgets($file))) {

                    $rowData = explode(",", $row);
                    $linha = array();

                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($headers); $i++) {

                        $linha[$headers[$i]] = $rowData[$i];
                    }

                    array_push($data, $linha);

                    //$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT 'clientes' SET nome='$row[1]', responsavel = '', endereco = '$row[4]', endereco_entrega = '', cpf = '$row[12]', telefone = '', cidade_estado = '', ie = '', cep = ''") or print mysql_error();

                }
                echo "<br>";
                /*if ($query1) {

                    echo "Tudo certo";
                }else {
                    echo "erro";
                }
                echo "<br>";*/




                fclose($file);


                //echo json_encode($data);
                //var_dump($data);
            }

             ?>
```

Comment: Explique melhor o seu problema, está muito vago.

Comment: Eu preciso fazer um sistema de importação de clientes, porem preciso separar cada cliente por parte usando um while, tipo o nome teria que separar de cada cliente para fazer um INSERT no banco de dados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando a função `explode` e tentando separar a string por vírgula, entretanto, o CSV está utilizando ponto e vírgula (`;`) como separador.

Outro detalhe, você pode usar a função [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). Basta apenas definir o terceiro parâmetro como ponto e vírgula.

```
$headers = fgetcsv($file , 0 , ';');
```

Comment: E como eu puxaria cada string? $row[0]

Comment: Basta apenas substituir no `while` do seu código, da mesma forma que o exemplo (removendo o `utf8_encode`)